# How do I change the approval email a user receives in yetanotherforum?

Tags: yetanotherforum, yaf

How do I change the email a user receives once I approve them for forum use in yetanotherforum?  I'm not sure which file to alter.

Instead of "you've been approved ....", etc., I'd like to have my own custom msg.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by opening up your forum, and then the languages folder.  Within the languages folder, choose the particular .xml language file you'd like to alter.

Once selected, search for

```
<Resource tag="VERIFYEMAIL_TEXT">
```

Underneath that is your message that's sent to users awaiting forum approval.  There, you may edit the text to your own liking.  Repeat the steps for any other language files you wish to alter.

I hope this can help somebody!